# Get image and caption in Angular Swiper

Tags: javascript, angular, swiper.js

I'm using the Swiper (https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-useful-swiper) to display a gallery of images and captions.

The code in the demo of this package iterates only through an array of image urls. I tried modifying by adding in a paragraph for image captions.

I want to iterate through 2 arrays (one is an array of links to the images, the other is an array of captions for the corresponding images.) I feel like this code almost works, it does iterate through both arrays, but it prints out 3 times, and not as a slider...

If there's a way to iterate through an array of objects (something I tried, but I got stuck with it too...)

Is there also a way to iterate through an array of classes and assign them to each div?

slider.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-symptoms-slider',
  templateUrl: './symptoms-slider.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./symptoms-slider.component.scss']
})
export class SymptomsSliderComponent implements OnInit {
  variants = [
     'hvr-pulse-grow',
     'hvr-buzz',
     'hvr-wobble-vertical',
     ];

   passes = [
      'Caption 1',
      'Caption 2',
      'Caption 3',
      'Caption 4',
      'Caption 5',
      'Caption 6',
     ];
     slides: Slide[];
     images = [
            '../assets/images/swiper-symptoms/fatigue.png',
            '../assets/images/swiper-symptoms/craving.png',
            '../assets/images/swiper-symptoms/chewing.png',
            '../assets/images/swiper-symptoms/restless.png',
            '../assets/images/swiper-symptoms/cold.png'
        ];
      config: Object = {
                pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
                paginationClickable: true,
                nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
                prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
                slidesPerView: 4,
                spaceBetween: 30,
                loop: true,
                breakpoints: {
                // when window width is <= 320px
                767: {
                  slidesPerView: 3,
                  spaceBetween: 10
                }
              }
            };
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

slider.component.html

```
<swiper class="swiper" [config]="config">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper test">
    <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img [ngClass]="variants" *ngFor="let image of images" [src]="image">
      <div class="caption"><p *ngFor="let pass of passes">{{pass}}</p></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
  <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
</swiper>
```

Comment: If my solution worked for you, then set it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove your `passes` variable.

> Change your images array to following:

```
images = [  { 
                'src':'../assets/images/swiper-symptoms/fatigue.png',
                'caption':'Caption 1'
            },
            { 
                'src':'../assets/images/swiper-symptoms/craving.png',
                'caption':'Caption 2'
            },
            { 
                'src':'../assets/images/swiper-symptoms/chewing.png',
                'caption':'Caption 3'
            },
            { 
                'src':'../assets/images/swiper-symptoms/restless.png',
                'caption':'Caption 4'
            },
            { 
                'src':'../assets/images/swiper-symptoms/cold.png',
                'caption':'Caption 5'
            }
        ];
```

> Then change your html to following:

```
<swiper class="swiper" [config]="config">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper test">
      <div class="swiper-slide" *ngFor="let image of images">
          <img [ngClass]="variants" [src]="image.src">
          <div class="caption">
              <p>{{image.caption}}</p>
          </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
  <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
</swiper>
```

---

Here is a demo: [**PLUNKER DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/LTilhhENk8fGi4i4wgC1?p=preview)

Comment: Hello I tried to run the Plunker Demo but it won't run. Can you help fix that ?